# How should I draw lines out of bounds of the button like attached picture?

Tags: android

I want to draw a custom button with red bounds, where lines are out of bounds of the button like the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is appropriate you can draw a picture (like one attached to your question) and use it.

You can use picture as a sourse for ***ImageView*** element. Then use this ImageView as a button (set onClickListener to it).

You can also try to create layout (***FrameLayout*** or ***RelativeLayout***) and use your picture as a background for that layout. Then put a Button element inside that layout. Try different **width**, **height**, **margin**, **padding** properties for Button and layout to place Button inside red rectangle made with red lines.